# How to prove $\mathbb{R}^n < \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I know that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}$. I also know that the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}^n$  is equal to $\mathbb{N}$, but how do I prove that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is smaller than the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You can start first by showing $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb N}$ is actually $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your choice of fonts is very inconsistent.

Comment: $|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}| = |\mathbb{R}|^{|\mathbb{N}|} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$. $|\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{R}}| = |\mathbb{N}|^{|\mathbb{R}|} = (\aleph_0)^{2^{\aleph_0}} \geq 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R}|\ge |2^\mathbb{R}|>|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}^n|(=|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}|).$$